# Scapy NTP request

Tags: python, scapy, ntp

I would like to get the `ntp_monlist` response of my NTP server.
Actually the packet is send but I don't receive anything.
Someone can tell me why ?

**Code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
import threading
import os
import sys
import socket

#Data to send
ntpip = "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"

packet = IP(dst=ntpip)/UDP(dport=123)/Raw(load=str("\x17\x00\x03\x2a")+ str("\x00")*4)
packet.show()
rep,non_rep = srp(packet)
rep.show()
```

**Reponse :**

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = None
  src       = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  dst       = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
     sport     = domain
     dport     = ntp
     len       = None
     chksum    = None
###[ Raw ]###
        load      = '\x17\x00\x03*\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
......................................................................................................................
Received XXX packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

As you can see, I never receive any response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple issues:

- you're sending a layer 3 packet, so you need to use `sr`, not `srp`;
- you need to specify a UDP source port;
- your NTP payload is malformed.

There are two issues with your NTP payload.  First of all, the first word of the NTP packet is defined as follows (RFC 5905):

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|LI | VN  |Mode |    Stratum     |     Poll      |  Precision   |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

You want LI to be 0, VN to be 3, and Mode to be 3, so this gives a first octet of 0 + (3 * 8) + 3, or 0x1b.

Second, the minimum NTP packet is 12*4 octets.

So you need to say:

```
packet = IP(dst=ntpip)/UDP(dport=123,sport=50000)/("\x1b\x00\x00\x00"+"\x00"*11*4)
rep,non_rep = sr(packet)
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, can please tell me how show the result of the ntp_monlist ? When I use rep.show() I don't have the wanted result.

Comment: You probably want to be using `sr1` instead of `sr`.  If you use `sr`, you need something like `for (snd,rcv) in rep: rcv.show()`.

Comment: The responce is "load      = '\x1c\x03\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x07\x07\x00\x00\r7D^\x9c\x11\xda\xd6\xe93\xb8\xd9\x06w\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xda\xd6\xe9\x94"Rk;\xda\xd6\xe9\x94X\xfa;\xf1'" How can I have it clearly ? Thank's